# Вывести из таблицы SQL все вылеты, совершенные 1 января 1900 года с 10 ч по по 14 ч

Tags: mysql, sql

Задача из онлайн-тренажера SQLAcademy. Есть следующие таблицы:
**Company**. Поля:

```
id(INT, PRIMARY KEY), name(VARCHAR)
```

**Trip**. Поля:

```
id(INT, PRIMARY KEY), company(INT, FOREIGN KEY)<->Company.id, plane(VARCHAR), time_out(DATETIME), time_in(DATETIME), town_from(VARCHAR), town_in(VARCHAR)
```

**Pass_in_trip**. Поля:

```
id(INT, PRIMARY KEY), trip(INT, FOREIGN KEY)<->Trip.id, passenger(INT, FOREIGN KEY)<->Passenger.id, place(VARCHAR)
```

**Passenger**. Поля: i

```
d(INT, PRIMARY KEY), name(VARCHAR).
```

Собственно нужно вывести из таблицы все вылеты, которые были совершены с 10 ч до 14 ч 1 января 1900 года. Ожидаемое поле *. Пытался делать так:

```
SELECT * FROM Trip WHERE
YEAR(Trip.time_out)="1900" AND
MONTH(Trip.time_out)="1" AND
DAY(Trip.time_out)="1" AND
HOUR(Trip.time_out)="10" AND
YEAR(Trip.time_in)="1900" AND
MONTH(Trip.time_in)="1" AND
DAY(Trip.time_in)="1" AND
HOUR(Trip.time_in )="14";
```

Так тоже пытался

```
SELECT * FROM Trip WHERE
time_out="1900-01-01 10:00:00" AND
time_in="1900-01-01 14:00:00";
```

И даже так:

```
SELECT * FROM Trip WHERE 
YEAR(time_out)="1900" AND
MONTH(time_out)="1" AND
DAY(time_out)="1" AND 
HOUR(time_out)>=10 AND
HOUR(time_out)<=14;
```

Но ответ все время неправильный. Есть кто решал эту задачу?

В любом случае подскажите хорошее решение, пожалуйста

Comment: Смотрите в сторону between, типо `where time_out BETWEEN '1900-01-01 10:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 14:00:00.000'`

Comment: Ну наверное всё же что-то типа `HOUR(Trip.time_out)>="10" AND HOUR(Trip.time_in )<="14"` и т.п., т.е. вылетел не раньше 10 часов, а прилетел не позже 14 часов.

Comment: @CrazyElf А дату-то тоже надо проверять...

Comment: @Akina А остальные проверки там правильные, которые на дату, я только про те, которые неправильно были написаны )  На примере первого запроса. Но наверное надо было чётче написать. Но тогда надо было бы ответ оформлять, а я не уверен.

Comment: @CrazyElf наложение функций на очевидный индекс приведет к грустному и долгому фуллскану таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Trip
WHERE time_out 
BETWEEN '1900.01.01 10:00:00' AND '1900.01.01 14:00:00'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Ваш запрос имеет некоторые проблемы в сравнении дат и времени. Вместо того чтобы сравнивать каждый компонент (год, месяц, день, час) отдельно, вы можете воспользоваться функциями для извлечения нужных значений из даты и времени. Вот как вы можете это сделать:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Trip 
WHERE 
    Trip.time_out >= '1900-01-01 10:00:00' AND
    Trip.time_out <= '1900-01-01 14:00:00';
```

В этом запросе мы выбираем все строки из таблицы Trip, где время вылета находится в диапазоне от 10:00 до 14:00 1 января 1900 года.

Если вы хотите учесть и дату прилета, то можно использовать операторы логического И (`AND`):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Trip 
WHERE 
    Trip.time_out >= '1900-01-01 10:00:00' AND
    Trip.time_out <= '1900-01-01 14:00:00' AND
    Trip.time_in >= '1900-01-01 10:00:00' AND
    Trip.time_in <= '1900-01-01 14:00:00';
```

Пожалуйста, убедитесь, что формат даты и времени в вашей базе данных совпадает с использованным в запросе.